# zum oder zu einem Kaffee/Tee einladen

Tags: article, definite-article

Is there any difference between ***der*** Kaffee/Tee and ***ein*** Kaffee/Tee when you want to invite someone for a cup of coffee/tea?

Which sentence would you prefer:

> Darf ich Sie zu**m** Kaffee/Tee einladen?
>   Darf ich Sie zu **einem** Kaffee/Tee einladen?

Comment: My first thought was: "Darf ich Sie zum Kaffee einladen?" = inviting to come to your home to drink coffee. "Darf ich Sie zu einem Kaffee einladen?" = offering to pay a cup of coffee somewhere in town.

Comment: Apart: I would invite someone "auf einen Kaffee".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These phrases have a different meaning:

> Darf ich Sie zum Kaffee/Tee einladen?

means that you are inviting somebody on a later date to your home where there will be some cookies too or maybe cake. So it's comparable to english "tea time".

> Darf ich Sie zu einem Kaffee/Tee einladen?

means that you are asking someone to drink a cup of coffee with you right away. This might also be at your home e.g. a neighbour helped you with something and you would just like to say thanks, but in most cases it means that you meet someone on the way and you will have a cup together in a café.

In this case you can also be more specific:

> Darf ich Sie zu einer Tasse Kaffee/Tee einladen?
>
> Darf ich Sie **auf** eine Tasse Kaffee/Tee einladen?

Comment: Du kannst zwar jmd. zu Kaffee und Kuchen mit "zum Kaffee" einladen, die Bedeutung ist aber keineswegs eindeutig sondern (wie so oft) vom Kontext abhängig. Es kann auch nur das Getränk gemeint sein. Zum Beispiel kann der Kaffee schon getrunken sein, und man will nur sagen, dass man die Rechnung übernehmen will: "Darf ich sie zum Kaffee einladen?". Es ist auch eine Sache der Betonung. Läd mich jmd. ins Cafe auf einen Kaffee ein, wäre ich vorsichtig mit Kuchenbestellung und würde beobachten, was der Einlader bestellt.

Comment: Wenn der Kaffee schon getrunken ist würde ich vor dem Bezahlen eher fragen "Darf ich Sie einladen?". Der Kaffee versteht sich dann von selbst, es sei denn man meint "... aber das Mineralwasser müssen Sie selbst bezahlen." ;-)

Comment: Dass Du eine andere Formulierung bevorzugst zeigt aber nicht, dass die andere nicht geeignet ist, die Idee auszudrücken. Die Nennung von Kaffee/Tee zeigt m.E. das Aussagen zum Kaffee als komplettes Ritual nicht gemeint war und nur eine Nebenbemerkung wert ist. Dass Leute mit beschränkter Liquidität andere nur zu eng umrissenen Konsummöglichkeiten einladen habe ich schon mehrfach erlebt, btw.

Comment: There is a famous Seinfeld episode where, after a date, the girl invites George upstairs "for a cup of coffee" and George turns her down because it will keep him awake. Later Jerry berates George for not understanding that in the particular context, "a cup of coffee"  actually meant sex.

Answer (score 3):

In the first form, this could be an invitation to visit the speaker at his or her home. The second form is a suggestion to visit a café.

Comment: Nein. Beides ist mit beiden Formulierungen möglich, sie bedeuten das gleiche.

Comment: *Gebräuchlich* sind sie aber so, wie in der Antwort geschrieben. Zumindest werden sie meist so verstanden.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, there is a large overlap in meanings (specifically, both phrases can mean *the exact same thing*, namely paying for someone else's coffee), but there can be nuances of difference.

The largest difference is probably that if you're walking along a street, chatting with someone about something and then say you want to continue the discussion

> Lass uns weiterreden. Darf ich dich zu einem Kaffee einladen?

would imply you're just approaching or you just passed a café where you would want to drink one. I personally would use a different preposition here:

> Darf ich dich *auf* einen Kaffee einladen?

The answer will likely be:

> Ja gerne! (implying immediately)

or

> Nein, ich muss leider <insert place where you need to go>. Aber vielleicht später/morgen?

---

On the other hand, if you said in the beginning

> Lass uns weiterreden. Darf ich dich zum Kaffee einladen?

The answer will likely be:

> Ja gerne. Heute? Morgen? Bei dir? Im Café?

Showing that *zum Kaffee* is often a fixed expression much like *tea time*. It *cannot* be modified to use a different preposition.

> <strike>Darf ich dich *auf den* Kaffee einladen?</strike>

Is wrong.

---

---

Meanings shift if you have already had a coffee/tea at a café, or if you're having a discussion in your office. In those cases, both phrases are nearly completely interchangeable.

Although, if you had a coffee already and want to offer to pay for somebody, you can safely leave out the coffee:

> Darf ich dich einladen?

---

---

**Note:** I have used the more informal *du* form throughout my answer, because it is hard for me to actually think and say *darf ich **Sie** zum Kaffee einladen?* I know that it's possible, and maybe in the later stages of my life it will happen the odd time, but inviting someone for tea time who I address with *du* is just so much more likely.