# Wie biete ich Gästen Kaffee an?

Tags: phrase, politeness

Wie biete ich Gästen Kaffee an? Kann ich fragen: "*Wollen Sie eine Tasse Kaffee?*", oder was wäre die beste Frage, wenn ich höflich sein wollte?

Comment: Ähnlich (englisch): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22994/zum-oder-zu-einem-kaffee-tee-einladen

Comment: *Wollen Sie eine Tasse Kaffee?* is a perfectly valid option.

Comment: If somebody says: "Ich will", it is slightly rough, "möchten" is more gentle and preferred, you can see in the answers below "wollen" is avoided also in the alternative questions.

Comment: @Thomas: Das stimmt jedenfalls bei "ich will", aber weniger bei "wollen Sie".

Answer (score 9):

Möglich wäre beispielsweise:

> Möchten Sie eine Tasse Kaffee?
>
> Darf ich Ihnen eine Tasse Kaffee anbieten?

Comment: "Tass Kaff?" geht auch. ;)

Comment: Wenn man grundsätzlich davon ausgehen kann, dass das Gegenüber einen Kaffee möchte, ist es auch möglich direkt mit `Wie hätten Sie Ihren Kaffee gerne?` auf das Ggü. zuzugehen.

Answer (score 4):

Könnte man verschiedentlich formulieren,

> Hätten Sie gerne einen Kaffee?
>   Hätten Sie gerne eine Tasse Kaffee?
>   Könnte ich Ihnen einen Kaffee anbieten?
>   Könnte ich Ihnen eine Tasse Kaffee anbieten?
>
> Hätten Sie Lust auf einen Kaffee?
>   Was für ein Kaffee könnte ich Ihnen anbieten?
>   Trinken Sie Kaffee? (vielleicht eine Aufforderung)

Oder die verschiedenen Kaffeevarianten aufzählen und nachfragen.

Comment: "Trinken Sie Kaffee?" is a very nice one, it opens a small introduction talk and is very nice in the combination with the offering later.

Comment: I finally used the "Was für ein Kaffee könnte ich Ihnen anbieten?". This is perfect to use in a situation when you meet a new person. Danke sehr!!